# Change check button label when pressed using CSS

Tags: html, css, accordion

I wish to change the color and the background of the button label when I check the button, but it is not working. This is a collapsible button.

```css
.accordion>input[name="collapse"] {
  display: none;
  /*position: absolute;
      left: -100vw;*/
}

.accordion label,
.accordion .content {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.accordion label {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff55;
  width: 76%;
  margin-left: 12%;
  text-indent: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.accordion .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.accordion>input[name="collapse"]:checked~.content {
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}


/* For Desktop */

@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .accordion .handle {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .accordion label {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal;
    user-select: none;
  }
  .accordion label:hover,
  .accordion label:focus {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .accordion .handle label:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f107";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.556em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .accordion>input[name="collapse"]:checked~.content {
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: 12%;
    border-top: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .accordion {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .accordion>input[name="collapse"]:checked~.handle label:after {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .accordion>input[name="collapse"]:checked~.accordion label {
    color: #000;
    background: #ffffff;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <input type="checkbox" name="collapse" id="handle4">
  <h2 class="handle ">
    <label for="handle4" style="">Change Language</label>
  </h2>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Some contents</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The very last CSS instruction is the one I'm trying to use to change the color and background of the label "Change language", but it does not work.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your sibling element shall be `.handle label` instead of `.accordion label`

Comment: Thank you, it works! How can i change the color of a different button (using CSS vs PHP) when THIS button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

you would need to change the instruction to this

```
.accordion>input[name="collapse"]:checked ~ .handle label {
            color: #000;
            background: #ffffff;
        }
```

the one you have will not work since there is no direct sibling that is .accordion